# A-Frame's camera rotation speed

Tags: html5-video, aframe

I am using A-Frame to render my 360 videos. I have the rotation set at `0 270 0` on the camera. When I rotate the video it is a bit slow. I tried to play around with the Y-axis angle but it doesn't have any effect on the rotation. I tried the `wasd-controls` with `accelaration` property too.

Is there a way to  make the rotation smooth and fast so that when I drag a mouse on the video it spins faster?

```
<a-entity look-controls="enabled: true; reverseMouseDrag: true"
  wasd-controls="acceleration: 100;">
</a-entity>
```

I tried using the `universal-controls` `rotationSensitivity` property but it was of no effect. Please advise. Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The wasd controls `acceleration` attribute only works on movement speed,
The look-controls, don't have a rotation speed attribute.

Don McCurdy's universal-controls from the [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras), have a sensitivity option, called rotationSensitivity, You can easily change it:

```
<a-entity camera universal-controls="rotationSensitivity:1"></a-entity>
```

Check it out on my live fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8gfmL1n1/.

Comment: I did try the `universal-controls`. No effect on rotation for some reason.